# Android multiple lists using @id/android:list

Tags: java, android, onclick

I've got a new List of things that needs to be clicked but this one isn't working. onListItemClick is never called. I have another one in my app that has been working as expected and I can't figure out what the difference is. It occurs to me that maybe there's some conflict since they are both using the provided @id/android:list but they're in different Activities and I haven't found other people complaining about the same problem so I'm not sure.

Here is a bunch of code. I would appreciate any suggestions.

Working:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
{
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    // get the item that was clicked
    v_ProjectInvestigatorSiteContact project = (v_ProjectInvestigatorSiteContact) this.getListAdapter().getItem(
            position);

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, Details.class);

    myIntent.putExtra(res.getString(R.string.project), project);

    startActivity(myIntent);
}// onListItemClick
```

Not Working:

```
    @Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
{
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    // get the item that was clicked
    final v_SitePeople vSitePeople = (v_SitePeople) this.getListAdapter().getItem(
            position);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Share.this);
    builder.setTitle(res.getString(R.string.forgot_password_check_dialog_title))
            .setMessage(res.getString(R.string.share_check_dialog_text))
            .setPositiveButton(res.getString(R.string.send), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                {
                    sendShareEmail(vSitePeople);
                }
            }).setNegativeButton(res.getString(R.string.cancel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                {
                    // cancelled, so do nothing
                }
            });
    AlertDialog msgBox = builder.create();
    msgBox.show();
}// onListItemClick
```

Working XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffffff"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<!-- dummy item to prevent edittext from gaining focus on activity start -->

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/title_background" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_logo" >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/logo" 
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="50dp"
        android:paddingRight="60dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/app_header"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/search_gradient" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/searchBoxIcon"
        android:layout_width="38dp"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/action_search" >
    </ImageView>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/searchBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="@+id/searchBoxIcon"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/searchBoxIcon"
        android:background="@drawable/search_box"
        android:hint="@string/search_hint"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:minHeight="30sp"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="25sp"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:textColor="#ff000000" />
</RelativeLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@color/divider_gray"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:divider="@color/divider_gray"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
    android:headerDividersEnabled="false" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/android:empty"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/loading"
    android:textColor="@color/loading_gray"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Not Working XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffffff"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<!-- dummy item to prevent edittext from gaining focus on activity start -->

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/title_background" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_logo" >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/logo"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="50dp"
        android:paddingRight="60dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/share_header"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@color/divider_gray"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:divider="@color/divider_gray"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
    android:headerDividersEnabled="false" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/android:empty"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/loading"
    android:textColor="@color/loading_gray"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is more on how the broken one works, just in case you want more code.

Not Working Row XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="6dp"
android:background="#ffffffff"
android:layout_margin="10dp" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/toptext"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/moreInfo"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:minHeight="20sp"
    android:textColor="#ff000000"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Not Working View Adapter

```
    @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    if (convertView == null)
    {
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.share_row, null);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }// if
    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    v_SitePeople i = items.get(position);

    if (i != null)
    {
        TextView topText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.toptext);
        topText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        topText.setMinHeight(40);
        if (topText != null)
        {
            if (i.SitePerson != null)
            {
                if (i.PersonTitle != null)
                {
                    topText.setText(String.format(i.SitePerson + ", " + i.PersonTitle));
                }
                else
                {
                    topText.setText(i.SitePerson);
                }
            }// if has ProtocolNumber
            else
            {
                if (i.Nickname != null)
                {
                    topText.setText(i.Nickname);
                }
            }// if does not have ProtocolNumber
        }// if
    }// if
    return convertView;
}// getView
```

Thank you so much for your help.

More code as requested.

Working setListAdapter:

```
    public void updateDisplay(ArrayList<v_ProjectInvestigatorSiteContact> vProjectInvestigatorSiteContactList)
{
    if (fullAdapter != null)
    {
        if (fullAdapter.isEmpty())
        {
            fullAdapter = new ProjectAdapter(this, R.layout.row, vProjectInvestigatorSiteContactList);
            fullAdapter = reOrder(fullAdapter);
            setListAdapter(fullAdapter);
        }
        else
        {
            filteredAdapter = new ProjectAdapter(this, R.layout.row, vProjectInvestigatorSiteContactList);
            filteredAdapter = reOrder(filteredAdapter);
            setListAdapter(filteredAdapter);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        fullAdapter = new ProjectAdapter(this, R.layout.row, vProjectInvestigatorSiteContactList);
        fullAdapter = reOrder(fullAdapter);
        setListAdapter(fullAdapter);
    }
}// updateDisplay
```

Working list setup:

```
    private class DownloadProjectsTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<v_ProjectInvestigatorSiteContact>> {
    @Override
    protected ArrayList<v_ProjectInvestigatorSiteContact> doInBackground(String... URLs)
    {
        return ProjectsHelper.parseProjects(URLs, CurrentStudies.this);
    }// doInBackground

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<v_ProjectInvestigatorSiteContact> vProjectInvestigatorSiteContactList)
    {
        updateDisplay(vProjectInvestigatorSiteContactList);
    }// onPostExecute
}// DownloadProjectsTask
```

Working adapter:

public class ProjectAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    private ArrayList items;
    private Resources res;

```
public ProjectAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<v_ProjectInvestigatorSiteContact> items)
{
    super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
    this.items = items;
    this.res = context.getResources();
}// ProjectAdapater

@Override
public int getCount()
{
    return items.size();
}

@Override
public v_ProjectInvestigatorSiteContact getItem(int position)
{
    return items.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position)
{
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount()
{
    return 2;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position)
{
    if (items.get(position).ProjectID == null)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position)
{
    if (getItemViewType(position) == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    int type = getItemViewType(position);
    if (convertView == null)
    {
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (type == 0)
        {
            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.row_header, null);
        }
        else
        {
            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        }
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }// if
    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    v_ProjectInvestigatorSiteContact i = items.get(position);

    if (i != null)
    {
        TextView topText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.toptext);
        TextView bottomText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bottomtext);
        if (topText != null)
        {
            if (i.ProtocolNumber != null)
            {
                if (i.WebIndication != null)
                {
                    topText.setText(i.ProtocolNumber);
                    bottomText.setText(i.WebIndication);
                }
                else if (i.ProjectName != null)
                {
                    topText.setText(i.ProtocolNumber);
                    bottomText.setText(i.ProjectName);
                }
            }// if has ProtocolNumber
            else
            {
                if (i.WebIndication != null)
                {
                    topText.setText(i.WebIndication);
                    topText.setMinHeight(40);
                    topText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                }
                else if (i.ProjectName != null)
                {
                    topText.setText(i.ProjectName);
                    topText.setMinHeight(40);
                    topText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                }
                else
                {
                    topText.setText(i.SiteID);
                    topText.setMinHeight(40);
                    topText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                }
            }// if does not have ProtocolNumber
        }// if

        // Coming Soon logic
        if (i.ProjectStatusID != null)
        {
            if (i.ProjectStatusID.equals(res.getString(R.string.feasibility_id)))
            {
                topText.setTextColor(res.getColor(R.color.coming_soon_gray));
                bottomText.setText("(Coming Soon)");
            }
            else {
                topText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            }
        }//if

        if (bottomText != null)
        {
            if (type == 0)
            {
                if (position == getCount() - 1 || getItemViewType(position + 1) == 0)
                {
                    bottomText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    bottomText.setText(res.getString(R.string.no_studies));
                    bottomText.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0, (float) 1.0));
                }
                else 
                {
                    bottomText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }// header followed by another header, or end of list
        }// if

        //recenters row headers
        if (type == 0)
        {
            topText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        }
    }// if
    return convertView;
}// getView

public static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView textView;
}
```

}// ProjectAdapter

Not Working setListAdapter:

```
    public void updateDisplay(ArrayList<v_SitePeople> vSitePeopleShareList)
{
        adapter = new ShareAdapter(this, R.layout.share_row, vSitePeopleShareList);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
}// updateDisplay
```

Not Working list setup:

```
    private class DownloadShareTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<v_SitePeople>> {
    @Override
    protected ArrayList<v_SitePeople> doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        return ProjectsHelper.getSharePeople(params[0], Share.this);
    }// doInBackground

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<v_SitePeople> vSitePeopleShareList)
    {
        updateDisplay(vSitePeopleShareList);
    }// onPostExecute
}// DownloadProjectsTask
```

Comment: The most important thing is both your Activities are extending from ListActivity, as that what the system expects once you've provided the default android:id/list attribute in your xml. Is this the case? Also, share the code where you set up each list and set the adapters.

Comment: Yes. They both extend ListActivity. I will edit the OP with the code you requested.

Comment: I would try to remove weight from relativeLayout in row xml. You can't use weight in relativeLayout.

Comment: What does it mean "isn't working"? Is it crashes or throws an exception? Or it displays a black screen instead of the list?

Comment: The list displays as expected but onListItemClick is never called when I click stuff.

Comment: I got rid of the weight from row.xml and it didn't seem to change anything so... I'll leave it out, but it didn't fix it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I figured it out. I didn't ever post the relevant code, or I'm sure you guys would have spotted it for me.

I copied a non working adapter from a working piece of code which returns false if the viewType is 0. And since my second list only has one type, everything was disabled.

Thank you all for your efforts. I apologize that I didn't give you the correct code.

Comment: I hope you have learned the pitfalls of copy-paste programming. When you have such duplication, it is usually best to refactor it into a reusable class and/or method.